# Slot not rendering inside parent component

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have defined a component here:

```
<script lang='ts'>
    /**
     * A baked-in CSS Grid component that can be used to create a grid of any size by
     * setting the number of rows and columns.
     */
    export let numRows: number = 2;
    export let numCols: number = 3;
    let rowPct: number =  100 / numRows;
    let colPct: number = 100 / numCols;
    // There is probably a better way to do this, but I'm not sure what it is.
    // This line is just to get the styles into the HTML, which sets the number of rows and columns.
    let styles: String =  "--numRows: " + numRows + " --numCols: " + numCols + " --rowPct: " + rowPct + " --colPct: " + colPct;
</script>
<style>

    .grid-holder {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: red; /* This is just to show the grid */
    }
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--numCols), var(--colPct)+ '%'); /* We use css variables to set the number of rows and columns, and
                                                                                                                                             the percentage of the available screen space they will use.        */
        grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--numRows), var(--rowPct)+ '%');
    }

</style>
<div class='grid-holder'>
    <div class='grid-container' style={styles}>
        <slot> </slot> <!-- The number of slots should be variable, but I'm not sure how to do that. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the (+page.svelte) code that uses it:

```
<script  lang="ts">
    import { ResponsiveGrid, SidebarNavWrapper } from 'rush-component-lib';
</script>
<style>
        :global(body) {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
        }
</style>

<ResponsiveGrid numRows = 4 numCols = 3>
"test"
</ResponsiveGrid>
```

I am using vite. When I look at the page source that is generated, I see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        
    <style data-sveltekit>body{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif}{}
.grid-holder.s-UHrVZpErX4Ls{width:100%;height:100vh;background:red}.grid-container.s-UHrVZpErX4Ls{display:grid;width:100%;height:100vh;grid-template-columns:repeat(var(--numCols), var(--colPct)+ '%');grid-template-rows:repeat(var(--numRows), var(--rowPct)+ '%')}.s-UHrVZpErX4Ls{}
.sidebar-wrapper.s-Ztvx8Ff-FkL8{position:relative;grid-row-start:var(--startRow);grid-row-end:var(--endRow);grid-column-start:var(--startCol);grid-column-end:var(--endCol);transition:transform var(--scrollVelocityInSeconds) + 's' ease-out;transform:translateX(calc(-100%  ));background-color:var(--bckgndHexCode)}.isOpen.s-Ztvx8Ff-FkL8{transition:transform var(--scrollVelocityInSeconds)+'s' ease-in;transform:translateX(0)}.s-Ztvx8Ff-FkL8{}
.sidebar.s-FH32guMyprS9{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:1}ul.s-FH32guMyprS9{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}li.s-FH32guMyprS9{margin:0;padding:0}a.s-FH32guMyprS9{display:block;padding:var(--lnkPadding);text-decoration:none;font-size:var(--linkFtSize);color:var(--lnkHexCode)}a.s-FH32guMyprS9:hover{background:var(--lnkHoverHex)}.s-FH32guMyprS9{}
.toggle-button.s-R0RFVw9QBFq_{position:relative;top:0;right:-100%;background:var(--backgroundHexCode);border-bottom:1px solid #999;cursor:pointer;height:var(--height);line-height:40px;text-align:center;width:var(--width);z-index:1}.arrow.s-R0RFVw9QBFq_{font-size:20px}.s-R0RFVw9QBFq_{}</style>
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">


<div class="grid-holder s-UHrVZpErX4Ls"><div class="grid-container s-UHrVZpErX4Ls" style="--numRows: 4 --numCols: 3 --rowPct: 25 --colPct: 33.333333333333336"></div></div>


            
            <script>
                {
                    __sveltekit_dev = {
                        base: new URL(".", location).pathname.slice(0, -1),
                        env: {}
                    };

                    const element = document.currentScript.parentElement;

                    const data = [null,null];

                    Promise.all([
                        import("/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/start.js"),
                        import("/Users/jamesnebeker/rush-frontend/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js")
                    ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
                        kit.start(app, element, {
                            node_ids: [0, 2],
                            data,
                            form: null,
                            error: null
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The slot is never rendered. I haven't been able to determine why, and any help would be appreciated. Am I creating a slot incorrectly? Or is it a bug with sveltekit?

Comment: The code is broken but should still be inserted. Properties in `style` have to be separated via `;` and you cannot add a percent sign in CSS, it should be added in the `style` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `styles` string is missing semicolons and the percentage of the rows/cols width should be included in the variable instead of `var(--rowPct)+ '%'`. Except for that, I don't think there is a fundamental problem.

Notice that with `<ResponsiveGrid numRows = 4 numCols = 3>` the values are passed as strings and are automatically converted to numbers in the calculation. With `numRows={4}` numbers are passed.

Instead of the `style` string the [`style:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property) could be used to set the variables.

> The number of slots should be variable

Why that? One slot for every cell? `the <slot> name cannot be dynamic` so maybe this isn't even possible. The slot items can be placed using the grid, possibly spanning over multiple rows/cols, which wouldn't be possible with a slot per cell.

Here's an example [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0f6367a020f2465f97bcd13495553e0f?version=3.58.0)

```
<script>
    import ResponsiveGrid from './ResponsiveGrid.svelte';
</script>

<ResponsiveGrid numRows={4} numCols={3}>
    <div id="upper-left">
        upper left
    </div>
    <div id="lower-right">
        lower right - 2 rows/cols
    </div>
</ResponsiveGrid>

<style>
    #upper-left {
        background: lightgrey;
    }
    
    #lower-right {
        background: #00abff;
        grid-column: 2 / -1;
        grid-row: 3 / -1;
    }

    :global(body) {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

###### ResponsiveGrid.svelte

```
<script>
    export let numRows = 2
    export let numCols = 3
    let rowPct =  100 / numRows
    let colPct = 100 / numCols
</script>

<div class='grid-container'
         style:--numRows={numRows}
         style:--numCols={numCols}
         style:--rowPct="{rowPct}%"
         style:--colPct="{colPct}%"
         >
    <slot></slot>
</div>

<style>
    .grid-container {
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--numCols), var(--colPct));
        grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--numRows), var(--rowPct));
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: `fr` is unfortunately not equivalent to `%`. `fr` is based on available space, so if a cell *requires* a larger amount of space it can lead to unequal spacing ([Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/808dcdb39d6642ca905190ab4ef91996?version=3.58.0)).

Comment: Thanks @H.B. for making aware of that